# react js material-ui native select set default value is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have a form in a modal, in this form a have some selects native material-ui components, i am trying to set the value of this selects when i trigger the modal open, but  when the modal is open the selects dont change, and then when i click one of this select, all of them change.

```
const handleClickOpenEditDialog = (rowData) => {
    setId(rowData.id)
    setEditQuantity(rowData.quantity)
    setEditQuantityType(rowData.quantity_type_id)
    setEditFuelType(rowData.fuel_type_id)
    setEditTruck(rowData.truck_id)
    setEditUser(rowData.user_id)
    setEditPrice(rowData.price)

    setOpenEditDialog(true);
};


<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="select-quantity-label">Tipo de cantidad</InputLabel>
    <Select
        native
        required
        fullWidth
        label="QuantityType"
        inputProps={{
            name: 'tipo_cantidad',
            id: 'select-quantity-label',
        }}
        value={quantityType}
        onChange={(e) => { setQuantityType(e.target.value) }}
    >
        <option aria-label="None" value="" />
        {/* options list */}
        <QuantityTypeSelect />
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: You can check 2 things. 1) Have the ```setQuantityType``` been called? 2) Is the ```setQuantityType``` getting the correct value

Comment: @alexiramosc Are you calling `setQuantityType` hook directly in the component? If `setQuantityType` is a hook, you should use another function, and call the hook inside the function.

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 i check that, the values ​​are fine, but the select does not change, but if I click on some other input, just set changes the select

Comment: @hotcakedev I tried but that's not why I think